# Facebook app URL not working recently

Tags: ios, facebook

We have a web based iOS app, and in one section it connects to a page containing the next code:

```
<div class="facebook"><a href="#" onClick="facebook_link()"></a></div>
  <script>
  function facebook_link(){
    var link = $.get("fb://profile/XXXXXX", function() {
    })
    .fail(function() {  
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open("https://www.facebook.com/yyyyyyyyyyyy");
    })
  }
  </script>
```

If the device has Facebook app installed it opens desired profile on Facebook app, if not it opens the profile directly on web view into the current app. This was working perfectly until this week, when suddenly, trying app on an iPad (it's an iPhone app actually) it didn't open Facebook app anymore, spite of having it installed on the device.

I have tried to look after a change on Facebook URL schemes, but I haven't found anything. I have get the id used on fb://profile/XXXXX through http://graph.facebook.com/yyyyy page; recently I have tried to other id's, like the FBID or the one you get in the direction bar when you look for a picture belonging to your own profile, but anything have work on the iPad.

Have anyone idea of what could be happening?
URL facebook scheme could work different on iPhone and iPad?
Thanks a lot